# JSF 1.2 hot reload

Tags: jsf-1.2, java-ee-5

I use jsf 1.2. In web.xml have specified the following settings

```
`<context-param>
   <param-name>
        facelets.RECREATE_VALUE_EXPRESSION_ON_BUILD_BEFORE_RESTORE
   </param-name>
   <param-value>false</param-value>
   </context-param>
   <context-param>
        <param-name>facelets.BUILD_BEFORE_RESTORE</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
   </context-param>
   <context-param>
        <param-name>facelets.DEVELOPMENT</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
   </context-param>
   <context-param>
        <param-name>facelets.REFRESH_PERIOD</param-name>
        <param-value>0</param-value>
 </context-param>`
```

But I can't understand why hot reload doesn't work.
I use java EE 5 and as server is weblogic 12.1.3

Comment: **I  use jsp in jsf**